# LWJGL3: Overloaded glBufferData methods

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL to call OpenGL functions.

The method [`org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15#glBufferData()`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glBufferData-int-java.nio.FloatBuffer-int-) calls the equivalent [OpenGL method](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferData.xhtml).
It has several overloaded variants in LWJGL, and the most used I've seen is with `FloatBuffer`, like this for a simple triangle (other unrelated OpenGL calls omitted):

```
float[] triangle = new float[]{
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  -0.5f, 0.0f
};

FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(triangle.length);
buf.put(triangle).flip();

int vbo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

But there are also variants that directly take an array, e.g. float[] as the data. Since I never saw that used in any code examples online, I wonder if it is discouraged for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the methods. with arrays rather than `*Buffer` are not *discouraged*.
You may not find example of their usage online *because the have only been added recently.*

AFAIK there is nothing wrong with using these methods, **execpt** they might be a fraction slower than the ones with `*Buffer` as the arrays (and their data) is in the head. Whether that is an actual performance concern is arguable and can only be identified by *profiling the specific situation*.

So just use whatever is more comfortable to *you*.